# dejar vacio un jtextfield si esta definido como entero para realizar en una operacion matematica

Tags: java

Saludos a todos soy nuevo en Java ,estoy en el tema de hacer una calculadora en  formularios `jframe` .Al momento de ingresar un valor en el `jtextfield` de horas extras me sale este error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   sunat.calculadora.(calculadora.java:22)     at
>   sunat.calculadora$4.run(calculadora.java:319)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

El código es este:

```
private void btnCalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


int sueldo, gratificaciones;
  int renumeracion_bruta_anual;
  int horas_extras, meses_pendientes;
  int renumeracion_neta_anual;
  double impuesto_anual_proyectado;
  int asignacion_familiar;

  sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtsueldo.getText());
  horas_extras = Integer.parseInt(txthorasextras.getText());
  meses_pendientes = Integer.parseInt(txtmesespendientes.getText());
  gratificaciones = Integer.parseInt(txtgratificacion.getText());
  asignacion_familiar = Integer.parseInt(txtasignacionfamiliar.getText());

  renumeracion_bruta_anual = sueldo * meses_pendientes + gratificaciones + horas_extras + asignacion_familiar;
  renumeracion_neta_anual = renumeracion_bruta_anual - 29400;

  if (renumeracion_neta_anual < 1) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usted no paga impuesto");
  }

  if (renumeracion_neta_anual <= 21000 && renumeracion_neta_anual >= 1) {

      impuesto_anual_proyectado = renumeracion_neta_anual * 0.08;
      txtcalculo.setText(String.format("%.2f", impuesto_anual_proyectado));

  } else if (renumeracion_neta_anual > 21000 && renumeracion_neta_anual <= 84000) {
      impuesto_anual_proyectado = renumeracion_neta_anual * 0.14;
      txtcalculo.setText(String.format("%.2f", impuesto_anual_proyectado));
  } else if (renumeracion_neta_anual > 84000 && renumeracion_neta_anual <= 147000) {
      impuesto_anual_proyectado = renumeracion_neta_anual * 0.17;
      txtcalculo.setText(String.format("%.2f", impuesto_anual_proyectado));
  } else if (renumeracion_neta_anual > 147000 && renumeracion_neta_anual <= 18900) {

      impuesto_anual_proyectado = renumeracion_neta_anual * 0.20;
      txtcalculo.setText(String.format("%.2f", impuesto_anual_proyectado));
  } else if (renumeracion_neta_anual > 18900) {
      impuesto_anual_proyectado = renumeracion_neta_anual * 0.30;
      txtcalculo.setText(String.format("%.2f", impuesto_anual_proyectado));

  }
}
```

Como se ve la operacion se realiza con un entero pero al momento dejar vacio el campo horas_extras este se vuelve String y no realiza la operacion matematica  dando el error de arriba.
Ahi alguna forma de dejar pasar sin escribir nada en el jtexfield ya que debo dejar vacio cuando este se requiera o alguna forma de solucionar esto.Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Una manera que se me ocurre, es que si `txthorasextras.getText()` no se informa, guardar en la variable `horas_extras` guardar por ejemplo 0, así podrás hacer las operaciones sin que dé error:

> "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException..."

Cambia tu linea:

```
horas_extras = Integer.parseInt(txthorasextras.getText());
```

Por esta otra:

```
horas_extras = (txthorasextras.getText() != null || txthorasextras.getText().length() != 0 ) ? Integer.parseInt(txthorasextras.getText()) : 0;
```

Esa *terminología* que he utilizado: `(condicion) ? valor1 : valor2;`  se conoce como **operador ternario**. Existen tambien en otros lenguajes de programación, no solo en Java. Te dejo un link para mas información. [Operador ternario](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/).